# Java timer speeds up with repaint

Tags: java, graphics, timer, jpanel

I'm currently doing some basic graphics with timer in a `JPanel`, but I cant figure out, why the timer goes up exponentially.

Here's my code:

```
public class panel extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
    int r = 20;
    Timer forgo;

    public panel(){
        setSize(400,400);
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawOval(r, 20, 20, 20);
        forgo = new Timer(1000,this);
        forgo.start();
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        r+=5;
        repaint();
        System.out.println(r);
    }
}
```

so as you can see I try to make an oval go to the right edge of the panel, but my console prints out something like:

```
25
30
35
40
45
50
55
60
65
70
75
80
85
90
95
100
105
110
115
120
125
130
135
140
145
150
155
```

after a few seconds, I can't figure out why this is speeding up.

Comment: what is wrong with this output ??

Comment: Paint is for painting, never change the state of anything that might effect the painting process

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're creating a timer in the `paintComponent()` method, which spawns a new timer every time the component is repainted.

The "speeding up" you see is the large quantity of timers you've created taking effect concurrently.

You could try creating the timer only once, which prevents this from occurring.

Answer (score 0):

As @APerson said the reason is a huge amount of `Timers` that spawns every time your `component` is repainted, when first time your component is called by the system it adds 1 Timer to the memory with time interval 1000ms, after 1000ms `Timer` will repaint the `component` which will cause to add a new `Timer` to the memory now the 2nd `Timer` will also add a new `Timer` after 1000ms when it will `repaint` the `component` and the previous one also and so on.